# just need a sed command to remove dot from short names

Tags: sed

I just want to remove dot between the words so how to write a sed command for this.
as: k.p.m then i need to remove dot
    m.p need to remove text 
but if a number is there then no need to remove dot
as:9.30 no need to remove

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: did you make any effort?

Comment: Where is "dot m.p" in "k.p.m"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one-liner may help:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1\x99\2/g;s/\.//g;s/\x99/./g'
```

A little test:

```
kent$  sed 's/\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\)/\1\x99\2/g;s/\.//g;s/\x99/./g'<<<"2.3 3.x f.b y.4" 
2.3 3x fb y4
```

So it changes

```
2.3 3.x f.b y.4
```

into

```
2.3 3x fb y4
```